# How to fix Index Error in Chess Dictionary Validator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey so recently I've been going through Automate the Boring Stuff and I just got done with the dictionaries chapter. Now I'm doing the Chess Board Validator. However when I do exampleString[x] it always says I have an index error. Here's my code:

```
#The example board to validate
board = {'1a': 'bking', '2a': 'bqueen', '3a': 'brook', '4a': 'brook',
'5a': 'bknight', '6a': 'bknight', '7a': 'bbishop', '8a': 'bbishop',
'1b': 'bpawn','2b': 'bpawn','3b': 'bpawn','4b':'bpawn',
'5b': 'bpawn','6b': 'bpawn','7b': 'bpawn','8b': 'bpawn',
'1c': 'wking','2c': 'wqueen','3c': 'wrook','4c': 'wrook',
'5c': 'wbishop','6c': 'wbishop','7c': 'wknight','8c':'wknight',
'1e': 'wpawn','2e': 'wpawn','3e': 'wpawn','4e': 'wpawn',
'5e': 'wpawn','6e': 'wpawn','7e': 'wpawn','8e': 'wpawn',
'1f': '','2f': '','3f': '','4f': '','5f': '','6f': '','7f': '','8f': '',
'1g': '','2g': '','3g': '','4g': '','5g': '','6g': '','7g': '','8g': '',
'1h': '','2h': '','3h': '','4h': '','5h': '','6h': '','7h': '','8h': '',}

#Main function
def isValidChessBoard(board):
    while True:
        blackPieces = 0
        whitePieces = 0
        bPawns = 0
        wPawns = 0

        #Checks for kings
        if 'bking' not in board.values():
            return("No Black King")
            break
        elif 'wking' not in board.values():
            return("No White King")
            break

        for i in board.values():
            #Checks if it's black or white, and if it's a pawn
            if i[0] == "b":
                blackPieces += 1
                if i == "bpawn":
                    bPawns += 1
            elif i[0] == "w":
                whitePieces += 1
                if i == "wpawn":
                    wPawns += 1

        #Checks if there are too many pieces on either side
        if blackPieces > 16:
            return("Too many Black Pieces")
            break
        elif whitePieces > 16:
            return("Too many White Pieces")
            break

        #Checks if a piece is on an invalid square
        for i in board.keys():
            if i[0] == "9":
                return("Piece on invalid square")
                break

        #Only get here if you pass every other check
        return("Excellent Job!")
        break

print(isValidChessBoard(board))
```

Now to be exact here's my error message:

```
  File "c:\users\chris\onedrive\desktop\python projects\chapter 5 - dictionaries\chessboardvalidator.py", line 32, in isValidChessBoard
    if i[0] == "b":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I'm very confused what I did wrong. So what I'm wondering is how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use empty strings to represent empty board spots. But then you check

```
if i[0] == "b":
```

which reads `i[0]`. But `""[0]` is an error - you can't get the first character from an empty string.

This is a common pattern however, so Python has a nifty function to help you:

```
if i.startswith("b"):
```

This doesn't have the issue with empty strings.

Comment: Plus you should modify it on the elif right after too 

Comment: @Gugu72 OP should replace every instance of it, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't learned that one yet but that makes it a lot clearer. Ty!

Answer (score -1):

That's because you are doing: `for i in board.values():` and you have many values empty, like `'1f': '','2f': '','3f': '','4f': '','5f': '','6f': '','7f': ''...}`. When the value is empty, it's still trying to get the position `[0]` of that empty value, and it throws the exceptions `IndexError: string index out of range`.
You could do this to fix it:

```
    for i in board.values():
        # Checks if it's black or white, and if it's a pawn
        if len(i) > 0: # Check if it is empty
            if i[0] == "b":
                blackPieces += 1
                if i == "bpawn":
                    bPawns += 1
            elif i[0] == "w":
                whitePieces += 1
                if i == "wpawn":
                    wPawns += 1
```

Also, as a comment, you could remove the `break` statements after the `return` statements in the whole code because that code is unreachable.